# How do I get the Google Maps 3 api to display an array of markers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to display an array of markers using a simple for loop, so far I have been unsuccessful. I have looked at other similar questions and answers over the last week and I have not been able to load the map with my array on it. I was hoping that someone could look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function initialize() {
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(48.0625, -90.4394444444);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: mapCenter
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var permitEntranceLatLang = [
       ['Gunflint District', 48.0625, -90.4394444444, 1],
       ['LaCroix District',47.9144 ,-92.322, 2],
       ['Kawishiwi District',47.9533333333, -91.7207898333, 3],
  ];


  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: new google.maps.LatLng(permitEntranceLatLang[i][1], permitEntranceLatLang[i][2]),
           map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
           return function() {
               infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
               infowindow.open(map, marker);
           }
      })(marker, i));
  };

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



 </script>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Renamed all from `locations` to  `permitEntranceLatLang`.
2. Defined infoWindow  `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()`

**[Read the documentation for more info](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows)**

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(48.0625, -90.4394444444);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: mapCenter
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var permitEntranceLatLang = [
        ['Gunflint District', 48.0625, -90.4394444444, 1],
        ['LaCroix District', 47.9144, -92.322, 2],
        ['Kawishiwi District', 47.9533333333, -91.7207898333, 3]
    ];
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < permitEntranceLatLang.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(permitEntranceLatLang[i][1], permitEntranceLatLang[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infowindow.setContent(permitEntranceLatLang[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gvfhg4sq/2/)

Comment: It sure is. You need to create it first. Give me a few minutes and I'll show you how to do it

Comment: No I don't.. OP needs to.. haha

Answer (score 0):

1. your posted code is missing a closing "}"
2. once I fix that I get a self explanatory javascript error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: locations is not defined
```

You changed the name of the locations array to `permitEntranceLatLang` so this is not correct:

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
```

Change it to:

```
for (i = 0; i < permitEntranceLatLang.length; i++) {
```

And your code works.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gvfhg4sq/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(48.0625, -90.4394444444);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: mapCenter
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var permitEntranceLatLang = [
    ['Gunflint District', 48.0625, -90.4394444444, 1],
    ['LaCroix District', 47.9144, -92.322, 2],
    ['Kawishiwi District', 47.9533333333, -91.7207898333, 3]
  ];


  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < permitEntranceLatLang.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(permitEntranceLatLang[i][1], permitEntranceLatLang[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(permitEntranceLatLang[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  };
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```